# Writing Sci-Kit Learn Matplotlib Example to File

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm trying to test out an example I found in a sci-kit learn tutorial but modify it so that I can write the resulting charts to a file. According to the documentation the best way to write to a file is:

```
with open('path\file', 'w') as f:
        f.write()
```

However, to my eyes at least there isn't a clear object to place as an argument in `f.write()`. What is the best way to fix this? Is the only option to simply find a way to some how wrap up all the separate plot features (e.g. `plt.xlabel("Sepal Length")`) and reference that? See below for the code.

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#matplotlib inline
sns.set(style='ticks', palette='Set2')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

data = datasets.load_iris()
X = data.data[:100, :2]
y = data.target[:100]
X_full = data.data[:100, :]

setosa = plt.scatter(X[:50,0], X[:50,1], c='b')
versicolor = plt.scatter(X[50:,0], X[50:,1], c='r')
plt.xlabel("Sepal Length")
plt.ylabel("Sepal Width")
plt.legend((setosa, versicolor), ("Setosa", "Versicolor"))
sns.despine()

with open('path\file', 'w') as f:
    f.write()
```

Comment: Are you taking about [`plt.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)?

Comment: @Leb Yes it turns out I am!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking but from what I understand, try

`pylab.savefig('foo.png')
 pylab.savefig('foo.pdf')`

Comment: That worked!  I didn't realize there was already a separate library that could address this issue.

Comment: Please don't use `pylab`.  This should be `plt.savefig` if you are using the state-machine interface.  I _could_ just edit your answer, but that seems rude.

Comment: @tcaswell Oh, so it's already built into Matplotlib as well, thanks!